# Too Many Requests ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm inserting roughly 4000-5000 records in a row, on average the insert requests are sent within 1ms of each continuously until all records are added. The whole import is wrapped in one transaction. The job fails with the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Failed.  Response code = 429.  Response message = Too Many Requests.):
```

I've traced the error down to my model.create statement. I know that there's no way to insert multiple records at once using ActiveRecord, so is it possible to increase the amount of requests I can make in a short period of time? Or, do I have to use a gem to insert multiple records at once? i.e. [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import)

I'm pretty sure if I caught the ActionView::Template::Error and backed off for a few seconds before retrying it would work, but is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide some detail about what the task you are actually trying to solve is? Why do you need to insert 4000 records in one request?

Comment: This import only runs once in a while, it basically takes a large amount of records from an external API and saves it into our database. The data from the external API comes in pages, but currently we're getting all the pages and storing it all in one go, so that it's atomic.

Comment: You might want to use a bulk-insert tool like that if you're doing this frequently.

Comment: Right, but beyond a bulk insert tool is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this error had nothing to do with our own server. One of the pieces that we import is from Shopify. After monitoring HTTP traffic I realized that when you get an order, and try to get the transactions related to that order, it's an extra request. So, we were attempting to make way too many requests and hitting their API limit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a background job to accomplish this? Depending on what database you're using, you can insert the new data concurrently.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but why would a background job help get around the too many requests error? Do you mean to throttle the requests in a background job?

Comment: Looks like you found the error. :] Could use background jobs to throttle if you wanted.

Comment: I'll definitely look into background jobs, I was considering using delayed_job, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Actually, on second thought I think it'll be easier to setup a rake task, and then schedule it using cron.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when one method itself call another method in a **recursive** fashion.

So if i have a `redirect_to` in one action which again sends a `redirect_to` to the same action..so in turn this which result in the **Too many request error**..

The same applies to rendering `partials` which itself has a partial rendering the parent,where a **parent view** is rendering the **child partial** which is also rendering a partial of **parent.**..so this becomes a recursive loop.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Nothing was being rendered during the import, but as it turns out it was completely unrelated to our own server. Thanks for your response though!